# Authenticate website user with smart card

Tags: plugins, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, npapi, firebreath

I am working on a web application where during the login process I want to fetch the smart card pin as inserted into the smart card reader through the USB port.

What I understand so far is that we can read the smart card using the PC/SC interface and by sending/receiving APDUs, we can retrieve the data as well.

However, my problem is that I would need my website to read this information from the smart card physically connected with the USB port of the underlying machine.

I could see some interesting plugins built on top of FireBreath like web card, however with a limitation that it can work only on IE. This does not solve the purpose as the primary browser we are supporting is Chrome. With NPAPI support out of Chrome, I am not sure how can still achieve the same without waiting for Firebreath 2.0.

Any suggestions will be a great help.

Thanks,

AJ

Answer (score 1):

The only way to make it work, is to have the user install an application that will communicate with your extension. Eg. The application will be listening on port 4444, and the extension will connect to that port via ajax to retrieve data about the smart card.

Comment: You mean to have a thin client, since I want this data to be sent to my website running on browser. That's not a possibility for me at this moment.

Answer (score 0):

FireBreath 2.0 is already usable, though the documentation is still sparse and you'll have to do some digging through the mailing list history (and possibly ask new questions here or on the list) to find answers to all of your questions.

Alternately, you could also use Native Messaging directly, which is the mechanism through with [FireBreath 2.0](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) works in Chrome.  The main advantage to using FireBreath 2.0 directly is that it works on other browsers as well and will be updated to support FireFox's native messaging implementation when it's done.